# Optimise Large Record Deletion Procedure

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, stored-procedures, query-performance

I'm creating a database that mirrors our production database, but is lighter and anonymised - for local development purposes.

Ensuring we've enough data to operate on as an engineering team, I'm removing all customers that have their `updated_at` date set to over a year ago. Simple process is to keep new users, but bin old or inactive users.

For this, I've created a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_old_customers()
BEGIN
    SET @increment = 0;
    customer_loop: LOOP

        DELETE FROM customers 
        WHERE id BETWEEN @increment AND @increment+999
        AND updated_at < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);

        IF @increment > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM customers) THEN
            LEAVE customer_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @increment = @increment + 1000;

    END LOOP customer_loop;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL delete_old_customers();

DROP PROCEDURE delete_old_customers;
```

So this procedure batches the removal into groups of 1000, and runs until there are no more customers to process.

I run the procedure like this:

```
mysql "$MYSQLOPTS" devdb < ./queries/customer.sql
```

Where the `$MYSQLOPTS` refers to a my.cnf file with the following options:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
query_cache_size = 0
```

The problem is that due to the FKs and references this table has, this process can take up to 3 hours to remove ~800k users; and of course, as time goes on, this is only going to grow.

This is running on a Quad-core, 8GB RAM, Digital Ocean Droplet; so I've only limited means to work within.

So given this, I'd love the opportunity to begin optimising this procedure to improve its speed, but I'm unsure of where to start. I'm also open to alternative methods to achieve the same aim.

Comment: Are you deleting far more than you're keeping? Instead of deleting old records, consider exporting only *new* records and inserting those into an empty database to generate your development copies.

Comment: @LowlyDBA Yes, 800k removed, 200k remaining. I'd considered this, but since the deletion causes cascading deletes on the related tables (`customer_addresses` etc.), which is desirable, I had assumed that a straight delete would be my only/best option.

Comment: Another problem with FKs.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the next strategy: the stored routine that fill up the table on each inserted record also delete few expired ones. This look like that:

```
BEGIN
-- lot of code --
INSERT INTO table ...
-- lot of code --
DELETE FROM table AS w WHERE w.expire < NOW() LIMIT 3;
END
```

Insertion/deletion ratio is set to 1:3 just to ensure I get the reasonable  removal rate even when incoming data rate become low due to daily/weekly/monthly oscillations. It is acceptable for established bases with low expired records count. If you want to perform initial cleanup, then you have to set the `LIMIT` to the value that do not insult your server performance.

If you have low incoming data rate then you can create the special routine ad hoc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE table_cleanup()    
BEGIN
main: REPEAT
  DELETE FROM table AS w WHERE w.expire < NOW() LIMIT 1000;
  UNTIL row_count() = 0 END REPEAT main;
END
```

Huge `DELETE` will be splitted into the series of small ones that can't lock the tables for a while.

Comment: `REPEAT` loop is indeed much shorter and cleaner than `DO WHILE` loop, for example https://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/12/deleting-huge-number-of-records-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a new `DATABASE` with the same tables.
2. Turn off FK checks.
3. Copy over the 200K rows.  (Consider doing it in chunks of 1K.)
4. Copy over the rows needed by those 200K.  (Might also benefit from chunking.)
5. Turn on FK checks.

Note:  Each chunk should be `COMMITted` as you go.  (Alternatively, have `autocommit=1` and don't bother with `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.)  If anything crashes, drop the new `DATABASE` and start over.

The steps can be performed on the target dev machine (or a 3rd machine) to pull the data from the prod machine.

I agree with the chunking code you present.  Here is another version (though aimed at (DELETEing`):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: Why Turn off FK checks , when there is delete Cascade for a purpose.FK table won't get deleted,which is a requirement.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to bulk-delete the things that would have been deleted by Cascading?  (And do it a lot faster.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try once another way,

1. Create new table with same structure `Newcustomers`" and insert current year record here i.e. less than 1 year.If require then you can apply `paging` logic here.

   Insert into NewCustomer
   from Customer
   updated_at >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
2. Rename or drop old table as per requirement.
3. Rename new table to Customer